# My terminal is not working

Tags: php, mysql, apache, terminal

When I open my terminal it says this [-bash: export: `=Thomas$ ': not a valid identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw27f.png).

I cant call my actions like i used to.
Example when I type `httpd` it says `-bash: httpd: No such file or directory`.

What can i do?

Comment: What is written in your `.bashrc`?

Comment: This question appears to be unrelated to `php`, `mysql`, or `apache`. Please remove these tags and instead tag `bash`

Comment: Where can i find my .bashrc?

Comment: Try `$ ls -la ~` or `cat ~/.bashrc`.  It seems like `~/.bash_profile` could be another potential source of such an error.